# JQuery, how to call a function when one goes to another input (or click outside the present one)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add the **"has-error"** class (if needed) to the **input 1** when the user clicks outside of it **or** press *tab* to go to **input 2**, here is my code for now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta input1="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">


          <div class="form-group form-inline">

            <span class="input1"><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" class="form-control" placeholder="input1"/></span>

            <span class="input2"><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="input2"/></span>

          </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I added the class "input1" and "input2", in order to effectively border the input with the color red or green (from the **has-error** and **has-success** classes).

Here are the functions that I use for now to have the color red or green on every key stroke (but it's not what I want):

```
function validateName(name) {
  var re = /^[ A-Za-z-âêûîô]*$/;
  return re.test(name);
}

function onkeyname(input){

$( "#"+input ).keyup(function() {

if(!validateName($("#"+input).val())) {

  $("span."+input).removeClass("has-success");
  $("span."+input).addClass("has-error");
}
else{
  $("span."+input).removeClass("has-error");
  $("span."+input).addClass("has-success");
  }

});

}

onkeyname("input1");
onkeyname("input2");
```

Comment: [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: @ChrisG Great, didn't expected to be so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description, it seems capturing the 'blur' event should be enough; that event will fire every time the input loses focus:

```
$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 1):

You say

> when the user clicks outside of it or press tab to go to input 2

Both these conditions trigger the `blur` event, so it is enough to listen to that event and do you validation there.

```js
function validateName(name) {
  var re = /^[ A-Za-z-âêûîô]*$/;
  return re.test(name);
}

$("#input1").on('blur', function() {
  var $parentSpan = $(this).closest('span');
  if (validateName($(this).val())) {
    $parentSpan.removeClass("has-error");
    $parentSpan.addClass("has-success");
  } else {
    $parentSpan.removeClass("has-success");
    $parentSpan.addClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

```css
.has-success input {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.has-error input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta input1="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <form method="post">


    <div class="form-group form-inline">

      <span class="input1"><input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" class="form-control" placeholder="input1"/></span>

      <span class="input2"><input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" class="form-control" placeholder="input2"/></span>

    </div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```